# Two finger scrolling or Edge scrolling are lagging on Ubuntu 22.04 (Touchpad)

Tags: 22.04, touchpad, scrolling

I found similar questions, but I didn't find a suitable answer to any of them. When I am scrolling it looks like it skips few line and continues scrolling again and again...

I am using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on a Lenovo Legion 5 15ACH6H with MSFT0001:00 06CB:CE2D Touchpad. I tried to play with xinput settings, but it doesn't resolve the problem.

Link to the video of the screen capture to see how laggy it is: ***[link (YouTube)](https://youtu.be/S9dcCPMrBNM)***

I tried to play with Xinput settings for example changing the speed of scrolling:

```
xinput set-prop 16 "libinput Scrolling Pixel Distance" 40
```

Or to instal synaptic:

```
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
```

But nothing works.

This question was similar but nobody answered it ***[link (ask ubuntu)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1293556/touchpad-sometimes-lagging-in-scrolling)*** or this post was similar in lagging but I have a problem just with scrolling: ***[link (ask ubuntu)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1072167/thinkpad-touchpad-mouse-cursor-laggy-choppy-ubuntu-18-04)***